# extjs how to pass parameters to the component config

Tags: extjs

I have this code:

```
Ext.define('...', {
   extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
   ...
   config: {
        mydata: [],
        myname: '',
        myid: null
    },
    items: [
       ...
       {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Go',
            tooltip: 'Click here',
            listeners: {
                click: function (item, e, eOpts) {
                    var config = item.up('container').config;
                    console.log('Data', config.mydata, ' Name', config.myname, ' Id', config.myid);                                            
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    initComponent: function () {
       this.initConfig({
             mydata: ['Data1','Data2'],
             myname: 'Hello',
             myid: 10
        });
    }

});
```

when clicking the button it responses `Data [] Name '' Id null`, the very same data in config default definition... how can I set this initial config the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the needed params in initComponent:

```
initComponent: function () {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        config: {
            mydata: ['Data1','Data2'],
            myname: 'Hello',
            myid: 10
        }
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do not work? maybe i misunderstood your question? Just updated the code, config was missing.