# Extjs how to use config property inside item

Tags: extjs

I have this

```
Ext.define('MyComp', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    id: 'myid',
    alias: 'widget.myid',
    xtype: 'myid',

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },

    config: {
        mydata: 'Hi there!!!'
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            fieldLabel: **this.config.mydata**, // this is what I need to do
            labelWidth: 100,
            labelAlign: 'right'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Go',
        }
    ],

    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

How can I use the `config.mydata` text as the fieldlabel? I tried `this.getView().config.mydata` and a sort of combinations, but unsuccessfully. How can I achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to read container's config because container is not rendered and due to which `config.mydata` is not accessible in its any of child component.

Now I am proposing 3 ways in which you can achieve this:

Refer [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2v2u) link for fiddle for #1,#2.

1- You need to assign this label after child component is rendered(shown as way 1 in fiddle) as below:

```
listeners:{
              //Way 1
              render:function(labelCmp){
                 var config=Ext.getCmp('parentPanel').config; //Get parent cmp
                 labelCmp.setText(config.mydata); // Assign label from parent cmp
              }
           }
```

2- Assign label once parent along with child is rendered(shown as way 2 in fiddle) as below:

```
listeners: {
             //Way 2
             boxready: function () {
                var config = this.config; //Get parent config
                Ext.getCmp('labelCmp').setText(config.mydata); //Assign label to child cmp
             }
          }
```

3- Use [Ext.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410667/why-use-ext-apply-in-initcomponent) method. Its reference has been given in one of your [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661036/extjs-how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-component-config).

You can use either of ways which suit for your application.Revert back if any query.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to copy the config variable into view model data by initComponent or any function that the config is set. It helps in case the config is passed from a parent component.

```js
...
viewModel: {
    data: {
        mydata: 'Hi there!!!'
    }
}
...
initComponent: function () {
    this.getViewModel().set('mydata', 'Hi there!!!');
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
...
```